# GZIP compression doesn't seem to work in htaccess

Tags: css, performance, apache, .htaccess, gzip

I am trying to imporve a sites performance but no matter what I try I keep getting a low score (21%) on "Enable gzip compression". Everything else scores in the high 90's to 100. It's really bugging me as it seems to work on some sites and not others.

The code i have in my .htaccess is below. The #BEGIN GZIP to #END GZIP is something new I tried from a comment on [css tricks](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/htaccess/active-gzip-compression/) but it looks to be for older versions of apache. How can I increase the score for "Enable gzip compression" through the .htaccess file?

```
FileETag MTime Size

# BEGIN GZIP
# mod_gzip compression (legacy, Apache 1.3)
<IfModule mod_gzip.c>
mod_gzip_on Yes
mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
mod_gzip_item_include file \.(html?|xml|txt|css|js)$
mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</IfModule>
# END GZIP

# DEFLATE compression
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript

# remove browser bugs
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
Header append Vary User-Agent
</IfModule>

<FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf|ico)$">
Header set Cache-Control "public"
Header set Expires "Thurs, 06 Jan 2016 14:30:00 GMT"
Header set Last-Modified "Thurs, 06 Jan 2014 14:30:00 GMT"
</FilesMatch>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
<FilesMatch "\.(js|css|xml|gz)$">
    Header append Vary: Accept-Encoding
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Is this programming? I think this could be better on [server fault](http://serverfault.com/)

Comment: Please run http://gzipwtf.com/ on your website (check the "details" checkbox). There you see which file types get compressed. Please post the file types whch aren't compressed here.

Comment: Hi Reeno, thanks for the link. I've put the site through and its telling me no files have been compressed which sounds about right as the score is very low on page speed.

Comment: Is GZip enabled on your server? What happens if you remove `<IfModule mod_deflate.c>` and the following `</IfModule>`? If you get an error 500, your server isn't configured correctly

Comment: I removed those lines and didn't get an error. i also ran phpinfo and it says gzip compression is enabled

Comment: Mmh... Try to clean up the .htaccess a bit for testing. E.g. only use the `<IfModule mod_deflate.c>` part. Maybe something interferes. If you don't use Apache 1.3, I'd delete the legacy part.

Comment: Note that PHP has built in compression which is different than Apache.  You need to decide where you want to compress.  For apache, try running `httpd -M` to see a list of compiled in modules.  From there you can see if you have mod_gzip or mod_deflate which requires different syntax.

Comment: The problem is that gzip is not enabled on the server. I've voted both Reeno and jeffatrackaid  for their comments. Not sure how to accept an answer from these though.